# Sliding tab layout for right to left languages

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm using [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) and i want to slide tabs from right to left, but i can't find a way.

I already try 'setGravity()' method but it doesn't work.

Comment: which language you are using for RTL

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I changed gravity of container layout in SlidingTabLayout.java and setCurrentItem of viewPager to the last item and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need try layout mirroring:

To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following changes to your app:

1. Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring. 
   Specifically, add android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in your manifest file.
2. Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end" equivalents. 
   If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart. 
   If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

from library android.support.design from newest SDK
and apply [Xcihnegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3540593/xcihnegn) answer above

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and fix this by this:

```
 private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        if (isRtlMode()) {
            scrollToTabRtl(tabIndex, positionOffset);
        } else {
            scrollToLtr(tabIndex, positionOffset);
        }
    }

 private void scrollToTabRtl(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int maxItemCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (maxItemCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= maxItemCount) {
            return;
        }
        View activeItemView = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (activeItemView != null) {
            int totalWidth = getWidth();
            int targetScroll = totalWidth - activeItemView.getRight() + positionOffset;
            super.smoothScrollTo(-targetScroll, 0);
        }
    }
```